# Attaching a database in SSMS gives error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, permissions

I am accessing SQL Server using SSMS, and a user with adequate permissions.

When this user tries to attach a database by using SSMS (by right clicking on database node and then clicking on attach), they get an error message:

> Cannot show requested dialog.
>   
> Parameter name: nColIndex
>   
>   
> Actual value was -1. (Microsoft.SqlServer.GridControl)
>   
>   
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.Grid.GridControl.SetColumnWidthInternal
> (Int32 nColIndex, GridColumnWidthType widthType, Int32 nWidth)
>   
> ...
>   
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabase.SetGridColumnWidth
> (SqlManagerUIDlgGrid grid, Double[] columnWidthRatio, Int32 columnIndex)
>   
> ...

If the same user uses a T-SQL command such as below, then it works fine:

```
CREATE DATABASE [hgnx] ON 
( FILENAME = N'E:\db\hgnx.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'E:\db\hgnx_log.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This doesn't look like a permissions issue at all, but rather a bug in the UI.

If you are using Management Studio Express, then you should consider two options:

1. Ensuring you are on [the most recent service pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438) (yes they apply to client tools as well), and perhaps [the most recent cumulative update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830140) as well.
2. Many of the bugs in the 2008/2008 R2 version of the tools have yet to be fixed, and likely never will be. Never mind that the Express version has limited functionality. So stop using the crippled Express version from 2008 R2; the fully functional version of Management Studio is now absolutely free as of [SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579). Yes, you can manage all of your 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 instances with the newest version of the tool.

In fact, as it turns out (thanks @Justicator), [this bug has only been fixed in the 2012 version of the tools](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/553392/actual-value-was-1-microsoft-sqlserver-gridcontrol-error-when-attaching-database), so looks like option (2) is your best bet (or, just not using the UI for this type of task).